# Efficient way to load Spacy model

Tags: python, performance, time

Here, is there any efficient way to load `en_core_web_md`model without importing whole spacy module? It takes a significant amount of time to load the python program.

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher, DependencyMatcher
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
```

Comment: You are loading some MB with this few lines of code. What do you expect us to do here ? https://spacy.io/models/en#en_core_web_sm

Comment: Look at [Modifying the default pipeline](https://spacy.io/models#design-modify) there you might get a seep up.

Comment: Ask this question on StackOverflow too. Typically StackExchange Code Review is for reviewing code, and SO is for getting answers to questions like this. You might get more answers there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading a big module can be expensive.
I see elapsed times in the ballpark of four seconds to `import spacy`.
You *could* choose to cherry pick just the parts your app needs
and place them in a new module,
but that would involve lots of tedious testing.

```
from spacy import displacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher, DependencyMatcher
```

Those two lines have essentially zero cost, so don't worry about them.
They certainly aren't introducing any inefficiency;
they simply rename existing objects.
Having imported the module once, we enjoy cache hits on
references to the loaded module.

And the medium-size `en_core_web_md` is what it is.
You apparently don't mind the extra delay
relative to loading a `..._sm` small model,
so it must be pulling its weight in your use case.

## strategy

There's some review context missing.
OP doesn't tell us how that `nlp` model will be used,
and what the interactive latency constraints are.

Some apps are going to have large startup cost,
and the usual strategy for coping with that
is to hang onto the initialized process,
recycling it for multiple requests.
So painful startup is amortized across a bunch of requests
which individually are satisfied with low latency.

In the data science community this approach shows up
most often in the form of
[Jupyter](https://pypi.org/project/jupyter) notebooks.
You might choose to go that route for your natural language processing.
Load the model once and re-use it in many cells.

Alternatively, you might make your app availble via
[Flask](https://pypi.org/project/flask-restx) API endpoints.
Again, expensive startup of a webserver daemon happens once,
and then low latency responses are served up by the endpoints.